# Libre calc Scatter plot with two data series

Tags: excel, point, scatter-plot, libreoffice

In libre calc, I have a set of data where some samples have been run with two different methods. I want to display them in a scatter plot-esc fashion but I don't know how to layer two plots in one. I am much more familiar with excel but unfortuantely I am not ear a computer

```
09      10      11      12      13      14      15      16      18      19      
99.93   99.89   99.56   98.7    98.16   98.46   98.46   98.53   99.56   49.51
                                                        99.88   99.83
```

That is a example of my data set. Is there a way to put two points at the same sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Type `=NA()` to every empty cell of data array (where you have only 2 points).
2. Make a line chart with 2 series - one will have only 2 points.
3. Select only short of 2 series and change its type as you wish - e.g. to scatter.

Hope that was helpful)